# Django next page and prvious page not working

Tags: django, pagination, django-templates

In my Django admin the previous and next page button is not working.it always go to the else part of the code. I don't know what's the issue. On clicking it always go on the same page

```
   {% load admin_list %}
    {% load i18n %}
    {% if pagination_required %}

  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if cl.has_previous %}
    <li><a href="?p={{ cl.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="active"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in cl.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if cl.number == i %}
    <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
    {% else %}
     <li><a href="?p={{ i|add:"-1" }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if cl.has_next %}
    <li><a href="?p={{ cl.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="active"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}

</ul>
  <p style="float:right; margin:10px;">{{ cl.paginator.count }} Projects</p>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: can you also attach your view code for this part - it might be that you havent stated changing the default 'page_obj' name in the view also just in case show your url path for this view.

Comment: i am using this pagination in whole app. i haven't created a view. if i am making changes it is being reflected. as far as i know the else part is working in all three cases for some reason rather than if part.

Comment: what do you mean you haven't created a view???